# how to filer the tables data in sql

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

Am using this query to filter the data but am getting all the DATA THAT I Don't want.

I want only the nodes and their child nodes where text in ('Terminal Blocks & Connectors','Interface Modules','Switch-Mode Power Supply','Professional Tools','Marking and Engraving Systems','DIN Rail Socket and Switches')

```
WITH Nodes (NodeID,ParentID,NodeText)
AS
(
select ID,parentID,text 
from umbracoNode 
where text in ('Terminal Blocks & Connectors','Interface Modules','Switch-Mode Power Supply','Professional Tools','Marking and Engraving Systems','DIN Rail Socket and Switches')
union all
select ID,umbracoNode.parentid,TEXT 
from umbracoNode 
INNER JOIN Nodes on umbraconode.parentID=Nodes.NodeID
)
SELECT  * FROM Nodes
```

Answer (score 0):

You've defined a recursive CTE, but you want to limit the recursion. I'd normally do that by counting how deep I've gotten and using a `WHERE` clause to specify the limit:

```
WITH Nodes (NodeID,ParentID,NodeText,Depth)
AS
(
select ID,parentID,text,1 
from umbracoNode 
where text in ('Terminal Blocks & Connectors','Interface Modules',
               'Switch-Mode Power Supply','Professional Tools',
               'Marking and Engraving Systems','DIN Rail Socket and Switches')
union all
select ID,umbracoNode.parentid,TEXT,Depth+1 
from umbracoNode 
INNER JOIN Nodes on umbraconode.parentID=Nodes.NodeID
WHERE Depth <= 1
)
SELECT  * FROM Nodes
```

It looks trivial in this case, but easily extends to whatever depth you want it to.